# SELECT and UPDATE jsonb value using jsonb WHERE clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgre and I am trying to find a solution for the below scenario

**bookmarks table Value**

[image: img]

If there's any titles value changes then need to select ALL the matching entries and update the title value ALL at once.

**Something similar**

```
UPDATE bookmarks set titles='test title 1 [updated]' where bibid=100
```

I tried to find the solution for the current scenario but couldn't.

Comment: This is exactly why you should not use JSON but store your data in normalised structure. Change the table to 3 columns `userid`, `bibid`, `title`.